# First REST API Call for the day taking more than 40 seconds

Tags: soql, rest-api, api, rest, apexrest

We have exposed a custom rest webservice to perform dml operation on Case. We have a custom metadata where we fetch for a particular record based on the request parameter and populate the values for Case fields and performing insert operation on Case.

The first api call for the day is taking more than 40 seconds and subsequent calls taking 3sec to 4sec. Also after inactivity in the system and a  call is made it is taking more than 30sec to return the response back.

External system is expecting response in 5 sec as the maximum timeout for flow execution is 5 sec and they are receiving timeout exceptions  as the first api call is taking more than 40 sec.

What could be the reason  that first api call  is taking more time to return the response.

We experiencing this issue in sandbox and the query we are making to extract custom metadata record as only one record in the system and also a selective query.

Any pointers what could be the issue and how we can handle it to have first api call also to return response like subsequent calls?

Comment: Can you get an Apex log of the offending slow transaction? That'll tell you which step is taking too long.

Comment: Yes we have checked the apex log and we were not able to find what is the root cause and have raised a support help but no help yet on the issue.All steps execution for slow transaction and subsequent execution is same and also time in the log is 2 or 3 sec for slow transaction but final duration is more..not sure if platform is taking too long to return the response

Comment: In the logs I find only the load time is more before the dml execution @Charles T

Comment: @Tanuja - Is it still the case. Any solution around this. because we are also facing the same.